# Anyone help me create this regex?

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to allow the following characters but I don't really know regex that well so I'm just wondering if someone would be kind enough to help me out?

Here are the charcters I would like to allow:

```
!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ Space ""(),:;<>@[]
```

Basically so people are able to enter their emails in the following format as well as the normal way:

```
'Name Here' <email@address.com>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide examples on what you have tried to use

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet checkout [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/). It's a great place to get more comfortable with regex and still figure out what pattern you need

Comment: Tried using this - /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/

Comment: @Codarz360 so whats the problem with that regex ?

Comment: @Codarz360 ran that regex in rubular, is [this](http://www.rubular.com/r/QKarqQ2c9W) not what you wanted?

Comment: @aelor it doesn't allow me to enter all of the following characters !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ Space ""(),:;<>@[]

Comment: better go and read some regex, you may like to start from regexone

Comment: @Codarz360 For clarification, where would you like to allow those characters? Anywhere? so `email @ address#{` would be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to allow any character?
See this [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jT1wU4)

The regex => `[!#$%&'*+-\/=?^_'{|}~"(),:;<>@[\]a-zA-Z0-9]+`
Captures any character between the [] one or more times.

Comment: "one or more times"? Actually zero or one time.  Did you mean `+` at the end?